# Using an if statement within a for statement

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I'm pretty new to java and I'm working on an assignment. I need to go through a number of cards, determine if all of them are facing up and if they ALL are, then return a congratulatory message.

I'm working on the code for looping through the cards to determine if they are all facing up or not. Right now, the code doesn't seem to be checking all the cards before returning a "true".

Is it possible to use an if statement within a for loop or am I doing it all wrong?

```
public boolean checkAllMatchesFound() {     
   for (int i=0; i<MatchingGame.NUMBER_OF_CARDS; i++) {
      if ((cards[i].isFacingUp()) == true);
         return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm is a little off, try to think your logic through a little more.

Comment: This method tests whether there's at least on card facing up. If this is the author's intention it might be totally fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two issues:

1. Semicolon after if which java will treat as null statement and hence wont check for condition.
2. Even after that, If you find any of the card is facing up, you will return true which contradicts with what you need and hence your logic should be:

   ```
   public boolean checkAllMatchesFound() {       
        for (int i=0; i<MatchingGame.NUMBER_OF_CARDS; i++){
              if (!cards[i].isFacingUp())
                   return false;
        }
        return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In these cases you typically use inverse logic. In your case the method will return true as soon as a card facing up was found without checking other cards. Hence:

```
public boolean checkAllMatchesFound()
{       
   for (int i=0; i<MatchingGame.NUMBER_OF_CARDS; i++){
      if (!cards[i].isFacingUp())
         return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: This looks like the proper algorithm, however, I'd suggest that the original poster of this question work a little harder before posting questions like this to Stack. I don't mean that as an insult, but as they say.. 'teach a man to fish...'

Answer (score 0):

You've a semi-colon right after the if statement. Remove it & it'll work.

```
public boolean checkAllMatchesFound()
{       
   for (int i=0; i<MatchingGame.NUMBER_OF_CARDS; i++){
      if (cards[i].isFacingUp())
         return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Oh! I removed the semi-colon, but it still returns true before all the cards are checked...

Comment: You will still see the issue "Right now, the code doesn't seem to be checking all the cards before returning a "true"." @SweetMello7 see answer by me

Comment: The algorithm here is incorrect, this will return true is /any/ of the cards are face up, not if they all are

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible. Your problem is just when you find a card facing up you return `true`. You have to return `true/false` after iterating all of the cards. You may do like this -

```
boolean isAllFacingUP = true;
public boolean checkAllMatchesFound()
{       
   for (int i=0; i<MatchingGame.NUMBER_OF_CARDS; i++){

      if (!cards[i].isFacingUp()){
         isAllFacingUp = false;
      }

}
   return isAllFacingUP;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Java 8 then you can make use of streams to do all of this for you.  The following will return what you want

```
Arrays.stream(cards).allMatch(card -> card.isFaceUp());
```

Or by using a method reference:

```
Arrays.stream(cards).allMatch(Card::isFaceUp);
```

Answer (score 0):

you open and close the if loop.within that you return the true in else part return false or otherwise you just assign any value of FacingUp() method.